# How can I distinguish between integer and character when using scanf()

Tags: c

I am just using the function `scanf()`. The code is below:

```
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("%d",a);
```

When I input 1, it prints 1 like I want.
But even when I input 1a, it print 1 like before.
when a user inputs something not integer ((ex) 2.3,12ab,1 a)
I want to show a user the warning like "input integer".

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: do you want people to input only a single digit or a whole number (i.e. 13445 would be valid?)

Comment: do `getchar()` after the scanf; if it is neither `EOF` nor `\n` then they must have typed another character after the number

Comment: a whole number like 12345. In addition, when the character step in like 123abc, I want to catch it and show warning.

Answer (score 4):

Read it all into a string with `fgets()`.

If you just want everything they enter to be a single `int`, walk the string and look for `isdigit()` on each char and then when you find that it is all just digits, call `strtod()`, if not, emit an error and re-prompt.

If you want multiple things parse from the same input line, then you need to parse the string with something like `strtok()` to get individual tokens one at a time, then look at each token and determine if it is a number by looking to see if each character `isdigit()` or is equal to `'-' '.'` and suchlike.  If so, parse it as a number with `strtol()` or `strtod()` (etc) (depending on what you see, int or float/double.) Otherwise, parse the token as a string or emit an error.