# How to scanf only integer?

Tags: c, scanf

I want the code to run until the user enters an integer value.

The code works for `char` and `char` arrays.

I have done the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    while(scanf("%d",&n) != 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        while(getchar() != '\n');
    }
    printf("You entered: %d\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is if the user inputs a float value `scanf` will accept it.

```
Please enter an integer: abcd
Please enter an integer: a
Please enter an integer: 5.9
You entered: 5
```

How can that be avoided?

Comment: Is this similar ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610457/how-can-i-distinguish-between-integer-and-character-when-using-scanf

Comment: It's not 'scanning a float' but rather stopping at the first non-digit. It will also do this with input "5xyzNotAFloatNumber".

Comment: So it can't be done with `scanf`? So one must always use `fgets`?

Comment: @1336087 it's not a **must,** but you better do. Yes, it **can** be done using `scanf()`, but `scanf()` is horrible and unsafe in the general case.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Thanks for your input. :) I know how this can be done using `fgets` and `strtol`, I would like to know who this can be done using `scanf()`(if possible).

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/36704392/5547353

Answer (score 46):

1. You take `scanf()`.
2. You throw it in the bin.
3. You use `fgets()` to get an entire line.
4. You use `strtol()` to parse the line as an integer, checking if it consumed the entire line.

```
char *end;
char buf[LINE_MAX];

do {
     if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
        break;

     // remove \n
     buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;

     int n = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
} while (end != buf + strlen(buf));
```

Comment: Hmmm Looks like the loop will exit if user only enters `'\n'`. Do not know if that is important to OP.

Comment: Sadly, scanf is a bit to big to fit in my bin. :(

Comment: Using `buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;` to "remove the newline" is a classically terrible way of doing it.  It removes the last *character*, whether it's a newline or not.  (Also it strays into undefined territory if the string it starts with is empty.)

Comment: I would use `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';` to remove `\n`.

Comment: In addition to the issue mentioned above, this solution has several  more issues: (1). It does not check whether the user input was too long to fit in the buffer. (2). It will accept input that is too large to be representable as an `int`. (3). It is inconsistent in that it accepts leading [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), but rejects trailing whitespace characters. See my answer for a solution which solves all three of these issues.

Answer (score 16):

Use `fgets` and `strtol`,

A pointer to the first character following the integer representation in `s` is stored in the object pointed by `p`, if `*p` is different to `\n` then you have a bad input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *p, s[100];
    long n;

    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin)) {
        n = strtol(s, &p, 10);
        if (p == s || *p != '\n') {
            printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        } else break;
    }
    printf("You entered: %ld\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't print anything until the user pushes enter, right? What am I missing?

Comment: @Tanner it runs until the user enters an integer value, as required in the question.

Comment: Okay, great. I am working on a similar problem, but which requires a prompt at the beginning and wanted to make sure I understood the logic here :) It works great!

Answer (score 9):

If you're set on using `scanf`, you can do something like the following:

```
int val;
char follow;  
int read = scanf( "%d%c", &val, &follow );

if ( read == 2 )
{
  if ( isspace( follow ) )
  {
    // input is an integer followed by whitespace, accept
  }
  else
  {
    // input is an integer followed by non-whitespace, reject
  }
}
else if ( read == 1 )
{
  // input is an integer followed by EOF, accept
}
else
{
  // input is not an integer, reject
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using the following pattern in `scanf`. It will read until the end of the line:

```
scanf("%d\n", &n)
```

You won't need the `getchar()` inside the loop since `scanf` will read the whole line. The floats won't match the `scanf` pattern and the prompt will ask for an integer again.

Comment: `scanf("%d\n",&n)` only reads the whole line (and then some) if a `int` was entered.  If no `int` was entered, input remains in `stdin`.  Using `"\n"` not only consumes `'\n'`, but it scans for any number of white-space until a non-whitespace is entered.  That `char` is then put back into `stdin`.  So `scanf()` will not immediately return when `'\n'` is entered.

Comment: See [`scanf()` and trailing white space in format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/) — don't do it if you value your user's sanity.

Answer (score 4):

> I know how this can be done using `fgets` and `strtol`, I would like to know how this can be done using `scanf()` (if possible).

As the other answers say, `scanf` isn't really suitable for this, `fgets` and `strtol` is an alternative (though `fgets` has the drawback that it's hard to detect a 0-byte in the input and impossible to tell what has been input after a 0-byte, if any).

For sake of completeness (and assuming valid input is an integer followed by a newline):

```
while(scanf("%d%1[\n]", &n, (char [2]){ 0 }) < 2)
```

Alternatively, use `%n` before and after `%*1[\n]` with assignment-suppression. Note, however (from the [Debian manpage](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scanf&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en)):

> This is not a conversion, although it can be suppressed with the `*` assignment-suppression character.
>   The C standard says: "Execution of a `%n` directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution" but the Corrigendum seems to contradict this.
>   Probably it is wise not to make any assumptions on the effect of `%n` conversions on the return value.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution is to think about it backwards: Accept a float as input and reject the input if the float is not an integer:

```
int n;
float f;
printf("Please enter an integer: ");
while(scanf("%f",&f)!=1 || (int)f != f)
{
    ...
}
n = f;
```

Though this does allow the user to enter something like 12.0, or 12e0, etc.

Comment: Note: When input is "abcd", code is still left in `stdin`.  Also, try this with input "2147483647" or "0.9999999999".

Answer (score 3):

Using `fgets()` is better.

To solve only using `scanf()` for input, scan for an `int` and the following `char`.

```
int ReadUntilEOL(void) {
  char ch;
  int count;
  while ((count = scanf("%c", &ch)) == 1 && ch != '\n')
    ; // Consume char until \n or EOF or IO error
  return count;
}

#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int n;

  for (;;) {
    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    char NextChar = '\n';
    int count = scanf("%d%c", &n, &NextChar);
    if (count >= 1 && NextChar == '\n') 
      break;
    if (ReadUntilEOL() == EOF) 
      return 1;  // No valid input ever found
  }
  printf("You entered: %d\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

This approach does not re-prompt if user only enters white-space such as only <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: in each pass through the loop, set NextChar = '\0';  However, , '\n', in certain OSs, is a multi char item, so define as 'int NextChar = 0  Then it will re-prompt when no char entered

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the idea - d o not think it will work.  When no `char` is entered (example: only `'\n'`), `scanf()` will not return until some non-white-space is entered.  The `"%d"` causes `scanf()` to consume white-space until EOF or non-white-space.   So setting `NextChar` to this or that will not make a difference.

Comment: @chux How would you modify this if it was to accept only positive integers? The modification of the first if `if (count >= 1 && n > 0 && NextChar == '\n') ` doesnt seem to work. Stdout doesnt react if we give for example `-125` but we have to enter input again  to show a message.

Comment: @Geo Papas `if (count >= 1 && NextChar == '\n')` is used to detect if a number was entered without additional  `char`.  It is within the _body_ of this `if()` that the additional  testing should be added to further qualify `n`:   `if (count >= 1 && NextChar == '\n')  if (!(n > 0)) continue; break;`

Answer (score 2):

Although it is generally not recommended to use `scanf` for line-based user input, I will first present a solution which does use `scanf`. Later, I will present a better solution that does not use `scanf`.

The `scanf` solution works by checking the remaining characters on the line that were not consumed by `scanf`. Generally, this should only be the newline character. However, since using the `%d` specifier with `scanf` accepts leading [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), it would be consistent if the program also accepted trailing whitespace characters.

Here is my solution which uses `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    int n;

    //repeat until input is valid
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        int c;

        //prompt user for input
        printf( "Please enter an integer: " );

        //attempt to read and convert input
        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) == 1 )
        {
            //verify that remainder of input only consists of
            //whitespace characters
            while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
            {
                if ( !isspace(c) )
                {
                    //we cannot use "break" here, because we want
                    //to break out of the outer loop, not the inner
                    //loop
                    goto invalid_input;
                }
            }

            //input is valid
            break;
        }

    invalid_input:

        //print error message
        printf( "Input is invalid!\n" );

        //discard remainder of line
        do
        {
            c = getchar();

        } while ( c != EOF && c != '\n' );
    }

    printf("You entered: %d\n",n);

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter an integer: abc
Input is invalid!
Please enter an integer: 6abc
Input is invalid!
Please enter an integer: 6.7
Input is invalid!
Please enter an integer: 6
You entered: 6
```

This `scanf` solution has the following issues:

1. The program will have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if the user enters a number that is not representable as an `int` (for example a number that is larger than [`INT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)).
2. If the user enters an empty line, it does not print an error message. This is because the `%d` specifier of `scanf` consumes all leading whitespace characters.

These two issues can be solved by using the functions [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), instead of the function `scanf`.

Performing all of these validation checks makes the code quite large, though. Therefore, it would make sense to put all of the code into its own function. Here is an example which uses the function `get_int_from_user`, which I took from this [answer of mine to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636446/12149471):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt );

int main( void )
{
    int number;

    number = get_int_from_user( "Please enter an integer: " );

    printf( "Input was valid.\n" );
    printf( "The number is: %d\n", number );

    return 0;
}

int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt )
{
    //loop forever until user enters a valid number
    for (;;)
    {
        char buffer[1024], *p;
        long l;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //get one line of input from input stream
        if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small)
        if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //attempt to convert string to number
        errno = 0;
        l = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
        if ( p == buffer )
        {
            printf( "Error converting string to number!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that number is representable as an "int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE || l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX )
        {
            printf( "Number out of range error!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
        //so that input such as "6sdfj23jlj" gets rejected
        for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
        {
            if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            {
                printf( "Unexpected input encountered!\n" );

                //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                goto continue_outer_loop;
            }
        }

        return l;

    continue_outer_loop:
        continue;
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter an integer: abc
Error converting string to number!
Please enter an integer: 6abc
Unexpected input encountered!
Please enter an integer: 6.7
Unexpected input encountered!
Please enter an integer: 6000000000
Number out of range error!
Please enter an integer: 6
Input was valid.
The number is: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not an optimal solution.. but uses only *scanf* and *strtol*

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {false, true} bool;

bool isIntString(char* input ) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if(input[i] < '0' || input[i] > '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char s[10];
    char *end;
    bool correct = false;
    int result;


    printf("Type an integer value: ");
    do {
        scanf("%s",s);
        if ( isIntString(s)) {
            correct = true;
            result = strtol(s, &end, 10);
            break;
        } else {
            printf("you typed %s\n",s);
            printf("\ntry again: ");
        }
    } while (!correct);


    printf("Well done!! %d\n",result);

    return 0;
}
```