# How to get a input with prompt using scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I am using c and I am a newbie.

I want to get a input (1 or 2 or 3) and I will give the user suggest;

```
printf("please do it\n");
printf("1. \n");
printf("2. \n");
printf("3. \n");
char opt;
scanf("%c"&opt")；
```

if opt is not 1 or  2  or 3 then

```
printf("error\n");
printf("please re do it");
```

and all is in a while(true) loop until user enter the `enter(new line charactor)` to exit;

and how to do it?

I tried to create a function.

```
void get_order(char opt){
    switch(opt){
        case '1':break;
        case '2':break;
        case '3':break;
        default:
        printf("error\n");
        printf("please re do it"):
        char option;
        scanf("%c",&option);
        get_order(option);
    }
}
```

but it not work.
thank you.

Comment: You state that this is in a `while(true)` loop, but there is no such loop in your code.  You should provide a complete example (including a `main` and all included files).  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also read http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: That is not a good approach, your code is using recursion, it will consume memory more and more while the user don't enter the correct input. Use a loop instead.

Comment: If your compiler lets `scanf("%c"&opt");` through, turn on more warnings or change to a better compiler.

Comment: Related question: [Validate the type of input in a do-while loop C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31633005/12149471) In my answer to that question, I provided a function `get_int_from_user`. That function may be useful for you, in the sense that it keeps reprompting the user for input until the user enters a valid number. However, the part about verifying that this number is between `1` and `3` would have to be added by you.

Comment: `scanf("%c"&opt");` -> `scanf("%c", &opt);`

Answer (score 2):

That is not a good approach, your code is using recursion, it will consume memory more and more while the user don't enter the correct input. Use a loop instead. Your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("please do it\n");
    printf("1. \n");
    printf("2. \n");
    printf("3. \n");
    char opt;
    scanf("%c", &opt); //correct scanf
    scanf("%*c"); //consume the line break
    while(!(opt == '1' || opt == '2' || opt == '3')) {
        printf("error\n");
        printf("please re do it\n");
        scanf("%c", &opt); //correct scanf
        scanf("%*c"); //consume the line break
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line `scanf("%*c");` will not consume the newline character if the user entered more than one character of input.

Comment: Better to use `scanf( " %c", &opt )` to skip over any leading whitespace.  Of course, better to not use `scanf` at all for this.

Comment: what should I use if not use scanf?@JohnBode

Comment: You can use other types of input handlers, but they are a bit harder to use. Like `getline`, `gets` and some others.

Comment: @riquefr you should not recommend [`gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry, I intended to say `fgets`, but I confused.