# Trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in C

Tags: arrays, c, integer, tic-tac-toe

So I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in C and I've gotten most of the code written out, no error messages, but I want to know what code to add to get the computer to play the game as well. I just don't know what else to add here to make sure the game is interact-able and not just the user typing in one letter and being done. If anyone could help, that'd be appreciated! The code is below:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  system("clear");
  
  const char ROWS = 3;
  const char COLS = 3;

  int rows, cols, tile = 1, choice;

  for (rows = 0; rows < ROWS; rows++)
    {
      for (cols = 0; cols < COLS; cols++)
        {
          printf("[%d]", tile++);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }

  printf("\nWhere would you like to put your X: ");
  scanf("%d", &choice);
  tile = 1;

  for (rows = 0; rows < ROWS; rows++)
    {
        for (cols = 0; cols < COLS; cols++)
          {
            if (tile == 1 || tile == 2 || tile == 3 || tile == 4 || tile == 5 || tile == 6 || tile== 7 || tile == 8 || tile == 9)
            {
            printf("[%d]", tile++);
            }

            if (choice == tile)
            {
              tile -= tile;
              printf("[X]");
              choice += 1000;
            }
          }

      printf("\n");
    }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add user input and processing to a loop.

Comment: if you can, avoid calls like `system("clear")`.

Comment: How would I go about avoiding them in this particular code?

Comment: What exactly do you want the computer to do? Perform a random move? Or do you want it to make a "good" move? Or the best possible move?

Comment: This seems relevant to your question: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/12149471)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about implementing a computer player, I think your first step shoud be to offer support for a second human player.

First, you will need some array to represent the state of the game board. A multi-dimensional array of type `char` seems appropriate, in which each `char` can have one of three values:

1. `'E'` for empty
2. `'X'` for first player
3. `'O'` for second player

You could define the array like this:

```
char board[3][3];
```

Also, you will need an additional variable to keep track of whose turn it currently is. A variable of type `bool` with the name `first_players_turn` would probably be appropriate. When it is the first player's turn, this variable should be set to `true`, otherwise to `false`.

I also suggest that you create your own function `print_board` for printing the game board to the screen.

You will also need a function `evaluate_game_state` in order to determine the state of the game, which can be one of the following:

1. The game is still undecided.
2. The game is a draw.
3. Player 1 has won.
4. Player 2 has won.

To represent these 4 possible game states, I recommend that you use an [`enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum), like this:

```
enum game_state
{
    GAMESTATE_UNDECIDED,
    GAMESTATE_DRAW,
    GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER1,
    GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER2
};
```

You can now declare the function `evaluate_game_state` like this:

```
enum game_state evaluate_game_state( char board[3][3] );
```

As long as the function `evaluate_game_state` returns `GAMESTATE_UNDECIDED`, you will have to prompt the user for input in a loop.

Here is my implementation of everything stated above, which I have tested a bit and seems to work, but I have not tested all corner cases. I took over the function `get_int_from_user` from [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636446/12149471) from another question, and made a slight modification, so that it accepts [variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic), so that I can pass a string containing `%d` to that function and it treats it as a `printf` format specifier. Although your implementation of using `printf` and `scanf` would also work, that solution has the disadvantage that `scanf` does not perform proper input validation, so I used my function `get_int_from_user` instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

enum game_state
{
    GAMESTATE_UNDECIDED,
    GAMESTATE_DRAW,
    GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER1,
    GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER2
};

void init_board( char board[3][3] );
void print_board( char board[3][3] );
enum game_state evaluate_game_state( char board[3][3] );
int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt, ... );

int main( void )
{
    char board[3][3];
    bool first_players_turn = true;
    enum game_state gs;

    init_board( board );

    while ( ( gs = evaluate_game_state( board ) ) == GAMESTATE_UNDECIDED )
    {
        //prompt user for input until input is valid
        for (;;)
        {
            int input;

            print_board( board );

            input = get_int_from_user(
                "It is player %d's turn.\n"
                "Please select a move (1-9): ",
                first_players_turn ? 1 : 2
            );

            if ( 1 <= input && input <= 9 )
            {
                int x = ( input - 1 ) % 3;
                int y = ( input - 1 ) / 3;

                //make sure field is empty
                if ( board[y][x] != 'E' )
                {
                    printf( "That field is already occupied!\n\n" );
                    continue;
                }

                //perform the move
                board[y][x] = first_players_turn ? 'X' : 'O';
                first_players_turn = !first_players_turn;
                break;
            }

            printf( "Input must be between 1 and 9!\n\n" );
        }
    }

    //game is over

    print_board( board );

    switch ( gs )
    {
        case GAMESTATE_DRAW:
            printf( "The game is a draw.\n\n" );
            break;
        case GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER1:
            printf( "Player 1 wins!\n\n" );
            break;
        case GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER2:
            printf( "Player 2 wins!\n\n" );
            break;
    }
}

void init_board( char board[3][3] )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
            board[i][j] = 'E';
}

void print_board( char board[3][3] )
{
    printf( "\n\n" );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
        {
            //add spacing if necessary
            if ( j != 0 )
                printf( " " );
            
            if ( board[i][j] == 'E' )
                //replace empty field with number of field
                printf( "%d", (i*3) + (j+1) );
            else
                printf( "%c", board[i][j] );
        }

        //end the line
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}

enum game_state evaluate_game_state( char board[3][3] )
{
    //check for horizontal wins
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        char possible_winner = board[i][0];

        if ( possible_winner != 'E' )
        {
            if ( possible_winner == board[i][1] && possible_winner == board[i][2] )
            {
                return possible_winner == 'X' ? GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER1 : GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER2;
            }
        }
    }

    //check for vertical wins
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        char possible_winner = board[0][i];

        if ( possible_winner != 'E' )
        {
            if ( possible_winner == board[1][i] && possible_winner == board[2][i] )
            {
                return possible_winner == 'X' ? GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER1 : GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER2;
            }
        }
    }

    //check for diagonal-down win
    {
        char possible_winner = board[0][0];

        if ( possible_winner != 'E' )
        {
            if ( possible_winner == board[1][1] && possible_winner == board[2][2] )
            {
                return possible_winner == 'X' ? GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER1 : GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER2;
            }
        }
    }

    //check for diagonal-up win
    {
        char possible_winner = board[2][0];

        if ( possible_winner != 'E' )
        {
            if ( possible_winner == board[1][1] && possible_winner == board[0][2] )
            {
                return possible_winner == 'X' ? GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER1 : GAMESTATE_WINNER_PLAYER2;
            }
        }
    }

    //check if board is full
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
            if ( board[i][j] == 'E' )
                return GAMESTATE_UNDECIDED;

    return GAMESTATE_DRAW;
}

int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt, ... )
{
    for (;;) //loop forever until user enters a valid number
    {
        va_list args;
        char buffer[1024], *p;
        long l;

        //prompt user for input
        va_start( args, prompt );
        vprintf( prompt, args );
        va_end( args );

        //get one line of input from input stream
        if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "unrecoverable error reading from input\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small)
        if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "line input was too long!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "unrecoverable error reading from input\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //attempt to convert string to number
        errno = 0;
        l = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
        if ( p == buffer )
        {
            printf( "error converting string to number\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that number is representable as an "int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE || l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX )
        {
            printf( "number out of range error\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
        //so that input such as "6sdfh4q" gets rejected
        for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
        {
            if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            {
                printf( "unexpected input encountered!\n" );

                //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                goto continue_outer_loop;
            }
        }

        return l;

    continue_outer_loop:
        continue;
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

It is player 1's turn.
Please select a move (1-9): 5


1 2 3
4 X 6
7 8 9

It is player 2's turn.
Please select a move (1-9): 4


1 2 3
O X 6
7 8 9

It is player 1's turn.
Please select a move (1-9): 1


X 2 3
O X 6
7 8 9

It is player 2's turn.
Please select a move (1-9): 6


X 2 3
O X O
7 8 9

It is player 1's turn.
Please select a move (1-9): 9


X 2 3
O X O
7 8 X

Player 1 wins!
```

If you want to make a good computer opponent, then I suggest that you take a look at [the Wikipedia article on Minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax).