# Asking for user's input until meets requirements, otherwise clear input buffer and ask again in C

Tags: c, input, while-loop, buffer

I've been learning C for a while now and I've run into a problem with asking the user for input that has to meet some requirements. What I want to happen is when the input is the wrong ex. The input is not a number but a character, I want it to loop until the data is correct.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int c;
    int number;
    printf("Insert your number: ");
    while (scanf_s("%d", &number) != 1 || getchar() != "\n" || number <= 0) {
        printf("Wrong input. Insert again: ");
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }
    printf("Your number is %d.", number);
    printf("\n\nEnd of the program\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program reads all the input as incorrect and is stuck in an infinite loop.
Any suggestions?

Comment: does the program prompt you to enter input and after you write it and enter it it loops, or it loops when you execute it without prompting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate the type of input in a do-while loop C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633005/validate-the-type-of-input-in-a-do-while-loop-c)

Comment: Don't use `scanf`.  It's more trouble than it's worth.  Read a full line, as a string, using `fgets`.  Validate it however you wish, perhaps using `sscanf`.  If it's no good, loop and prompt the user to try again.  See [What can I use for input conversion instead of `scanf`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537)