# correct implementation of the do-while loop with bool data type in C

Tags: c

I want to create  a do-while loop such that the loop only breaks when the correct input has been entered by the user.However, this code only does two iterations before exiting the loop. For this i'm primarily making use of the read(), write()  and atoi() functions within the do-while loop.

I was expecting the loop to continue for cases where only alphabets were passed such "tata" or in the case where a 5-digit number was passed such as "12345". The only condition that was supposed to end the loop is if a 4-digit number was passed such as "1234". Instead the Loop only runs twice even without testing if the correct condition was passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ssize_t num;
    char guess[5], *red_alert="Wrong Input\n";
    int numb;
    
    bool is_valid_input=false; // we will start with an assumption that its wrong
    
    do{
        num=read(0, guess, sizeof(guess)); // read in the value from input;
        numb=atoi(guess); // converts our input to a number
        
        if (num == 0){// if num = 0, it means End-Of-File (EOF)
            break;
        }
        if (numb == 0 || numb > 9999){ /* if numb equals 0, then it means only alphabets were entered as  input and if the value of numb is greater 9999, then a 5-digit number was entered as input.
        */
            write(1,red_alert,strlen(red_alert)); /* will send wrong input message to stdout and retain the 
            value assigned to "is_valid_input".
            */
        }
        if (numb>= 1000 && numb <= 9999){// this means that a 4 digit input was entered.
            is_valid_input=true; /*This should be the only reason why the loop should end
            */
        }
    }
    while(is_valid_input == false);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show the **verbatim** input. But anyway `read` is probably not what you need here, you rather need `fgets(..., stdin)`.

Comment: Use a bigger buffer too, say `char guess[32]`. There is no reason to be so tight with that, and if the user enters say `100000` the `read` will leave some of it in the input buffer. But to exceed the larger buffer the user has to be fooling around.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate the type of input in a do-while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633005/validate-the-type-of-input-in-a-do-while-loop)

Comment: Aside: Use a better conversion function, preferably one from the ```strto*``` family.

Comment: `atoi` needs a NUL-terminated C string as argument, and you don't provide that.

Comment: ```read``` returns -1 on failure, and but you don't check for it.

Comment: My proposed duplicate question does not test the number of digits in the number. However, testing whether the number is in the range `1000` to `9999` is the easy part of the problem.

Comment: Better style to write `while (! is_valid_input)` than to write `while (valid_input == false)`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky,   The Question only permits the use of the read() and write() functions. other functions like fgets() or scanf() are prohibited

Comment: @AjekweMoses that's crucial information you didn't put in the question

Comment: Please [edit] and show a complete example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

### Invalid argument to `atoi ()`:

From the man page:

> The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string
> pointed to by nptr to int.  The behavior is the same as

```
  strtol(nptr, NULL, 10);
```

> except that atoi() does not detect errors.

`atoi ()` expects a string, where a string is an array of null-terminated characters . You did not null-terminate the buffer.

The man page further states:

> errno is not set on error so there is no way to distinguish
> between 0 as an error and as the converted value.  No checks for
> overflow or underflow are done.  Only base-10 input can be
> converted.  It is recommended to instead use the strtol() and
> strtoul() family of functions in new programs.

`atoi ()` doesn't provide any error checking mechanism. Consider using `strtol ()` instead, and check its return value.

---

### Ignoring the return value of library functions:

Your code breaks the 6th commandment of Henry Stephen's *The Ten Commandments for C Programmers*, which states:

> If a function be advertised to return an error code in the event of
> difficulties, thou shalt check for that code, yea, even though the
> checks triple the size of thy code and produce aches in thy typing
> fingers, for if thou thinkest ``it cannot happen to me'', the gods
> shall surely punish thee for thy arrogance.

From `read ()`'s and `write ()`'s man page:

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates
> end of file)
> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.

```
  num=read(0, guess, sizeof(guess);
```

stores the contents in `guess` and the return value of `read ()` in `num`, which might be the number of bytes `read ()` read, or -1. Your code assumes the contents are stored in `num`, and you do not check for an error condition either.

---

Consider using `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO`, and `STDERR_FILENO` which are defined as 0, 1, and 2 respectively in the `unistd.h` header file.
It improves readability.

But you do not need the `read ()` function here. Use `fgets` instead.

---

### Invalid argument to `strlen ()`:

In the call to `write ()`:

```
write(1,red_alert,strlen(red_alert))
```

`strlen ()` expects a null-terminated string, but as it's not, it continues to search for a null-byte in memory because it has no way of knowing when to stop.

### Do not compare against `true` and `false`:

> Redundant comparisons quickly become unreadable and clutter your code. If you have a conditional that depends on a truth value, use that truth value directly as the condition.
> *— Modern C, Jens Gustedt*

```
while(is_valid_input == false)
```

can be rewritten as:

```
while (!is_valid_input)
```

Similarly,

```
while (is_valid_true == true)
```

can be rewritten as:

```
while (is_valid_true)
```