# scanf() for Integer OR Character

Tags: c, scanf

So let's say I have a while loop that will end when the condition "isDone" is set to true. Inside the while loop, I ask the user to either enter an integer to continue the loop or a character to end it (by setting "isDone" to true).

How would I go about this using only **one** scanf()?

Comment: You should not use `scanf` for user input at all. Use `fgets` or something like it instead.

Comment: Take a look at `scanf`’s return value!

Comment: You simply need to account for the `'\n'` that remains in the input buffer after integer input. Since leading *whitespace* is **NOT** discarded for the `%c` format specifier, you must remove the `'\n'` and any additional stray characters before attempting to read the `char`, e.g. `int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();` Then read your character. (and no you can't use the same `scanf`. Using `%d` will result in a *matching failure* for anything other than `[0-9]`)

Comment: Question unclear, need more exact spec for valid inputs and invalid inputs. What if user enters two non-integer characters for example, or integer and character? What about a decimal number? Two numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scanf only integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583717/how-to-scanf-only-integer)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Or you could make the habit of tossing in an empty `getchar()` after each `scanf`, to chew up the line feed left in stdin.

Comment: Well, you could, but that doesn't protect against the user doing something dumb like entering `43abc`, which `scanf ("%d", ...)` will convert `43` leaving `abc\n` in the input buffer. It's the old circular-firing-squad of `scanf` for mixed input problem -- doable, but each `I` and `T` must be dotted.

Comment: A solution is possible with `" %c%d"`, yet the amount of post processing is not even worthy of an academic exercise as  compared to first reading with `fgets()`.

Answer (score 5):

The suggestion above is good advice: you're probably better off not using `scanf()` at all.  It might be better to use something like [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead, and then parse the string.  Or even better, just use [getchar()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm).

But anyway ...

Remember that, in C, a "character" *IS* an integer.  So just `scanf("%c", &i)` and check if you've got an "integer" ([isdigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm)) or a "character" ([isalpha()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isalpha.htm)).

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Excellent point, thank you.  I've updated my post.

Comment: Yep, unless the new programmer wants to get way down in the weeds of `scanf` -- line oriented input is the way to go.