# How to read integer values, until the character 'o' is struck in C?

Tags: c

so my problem is that I need to read integer values from the user, until the character 'o' is entered. I do not know how to differentiate a character from from a number, when reading values from the user.

I wanted to use a do while, it felt pretty natural.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int a;

    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &a);
    } while (a != 'o');
}
```

but of course I can not use %d for the character that I will enter while the program runs.

So the program should read integers from the user, until a specific character ('o' in this case) is entered. right now, after I input a character it will not read my input, the program will just hang there.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf() for Integer OR Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725845/scanf-for-integer-or-character)

Comment: `char a;
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("%c\n",a);`

Comment: Will the size be enough if I use a char though? I want any signed integer until I input the character 'o', I will later insert the numbers into a stack by the way, just need to get that part cleared first. thanks

Answer (score 0):

May not be idea solution but
my suggestion is don't use same variable to read integer and character, 
instead you can use another `char` variable to read character, if input 'o' it will exit
else it will read 'return' char when you hit enter and get read to read next integer.
I have modified program bit to do that(as scanf() ignore char 'o', getchar() will read it and then it exits from  while loop)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
   int a;
   char c;

   do
   {
      scanf("%d", &a);
      c = getchar();
   } while (c != 'o');

 }
```

Comment: This might actually work, with the restraints that were given to us by our professor. I would love to see an ideal solution though :D thanks for your solution!!