# C Integer Safe Input

Tags: c, integer, scanf, gets

How can I get a safe input of integer (especially, positive number) using `scanf` or `gets`? I've tried several solutions and each solution had some problems.

**1. Using `getchar()` to remove string inputs**

```
int safeInput() {
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    while(getchar() != '\n');
    return input;
}
```

This method effectively handles string inputs, however, if strings such as `3a` are inputted, the value of `input` becomes `3`, which is not a true exception handle.

**2. Retrieving input as a string then converting to integer value.**

```
int safeInput() {
    char[200] input, safe_input;
    gets(input);
    // I know about the security issue about gets - but it's not the point.

    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (input[i] >= 48 && input[i] <= 57) safe_input[i] = input[i];
        else break;
        i++;
    }

    return atoi(safe_input);
}
```

This method has problem that it cannot handle if string that has longer length than allocated to `input` was inputted.

**3. What if defining a string using pointer?**

I concerned about defining `input` by pointer, like `char *input;`. However, once I executed `gets(input)`(or `scanf("%s", input)`), it raised runtime-error.

---

So what is a proper way to retrieve an integer value from console window using `scanf` or `gets`?

Comment: Don't use `gets`.

Comment: Concerning the 3rd method: `char *input;` just declares a pointer, but `input` points nowhere, it's not initialized. Read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book. on't use `gets`. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: So what's the problem with method 2?

Comment: BTW in method 2 you forgot to NUL terminate the string in `safe_input`. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: 1. read line-wise (`fgets()`), 2. parse the input (`strtol()` and friends). See also my [beginners' guide away from scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: @MichaelWalz An overflow input. I know about the NULL termination but I didn't add there it's not the point

Comment: Does your system provide the POSIX `getline` function?

Comment: @GreenRoof well without the NUL terminator it's just totally wrong. And, yes an input overflow _is_  a problem if you use `gets`. It is not if you use `fgets`.

Comment: If `getline` is not available to you, you can write your own. https://stackoverflow.com/q/314401/315052

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what exactly you mean by *safe*. If you want to catch any possible input error, your only option is to use a function of the `strtol()` family, which even allows for a range check. In my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), I'm describing its use.

Here's the code adapted to what you're attempting here, with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

// return success as boolean (0, 1), on success write result through *number:
int safeInput(int *number)
{
    long a;
    char buf[1024]; // use 1KiB just to be sure

    if (!fgets(buf, 1024, stdin))
    {
        // reading input failed:
        return 0;
    }

    // have some input, convert it to integer:
    char *endptr;

    errno = 0; // reset error number
    a = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);
    if (errno == ERANGE)
    {
        // out of range for a long
        return 0;
    }
    if (endptr == buf)
    {
        // no character was read
        return 0;
    }
    if (*endptr && *endptr != '\n')
    {
        // *endptr is neither end of string nor newline,
        // so we didn't convert the *whole* input
        return 0;
    }
    if (a > INT_MAX || a < INT_MIN)
    {
        // result will not fit in an int
        return 0;
    }

    // write result through the pointer passed
    *number = (int) a;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you want a safe input, **do not use `gets`**. Saying that you know about the issues is not a true excuse when you could use `fgets`. Next, the trick is to try to read a non blank character after the int: if you find no one, then there is nothing after the int on the line.

```
int safeInput(int *input) {   // the return value is the indicator of failed read
    int c;
    char dummy[2];  // never forget the terminating null!
    if (scanf("%d%1s", input, dummy) == 1) return 1;
    // in case of error, skip anything up to end of line or end of file
    while (((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && (c != EOF));
    return 0;
}
```

The nice point here, is that when `scanf` returns 1, the `%1s` has eaten anything up to the end of line, *including the terminating '`n'`*. But this has a major drawback: the `scanf` will only end on end of stream or after reading one additional (non blank) character. For that reason, Felix Palmen's answer is easier and safer to use.

Comment: looks nice if you insist using `scanf()` -- shouldn't `%*1s` work as well, so you don't need a dummy buffer?

Comment: There is another weakness to using `scanf` not mentioned in the question, which is it will overflow if the input is larger than what the type can hold.

Comment: The `%1s` trick doesn’t work.  It skips over white space and demands something that’s not white space before it returns. It will eat all the newlines you type until you type something that’s not white space.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think this question is largely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583717/how-to-scanf-only-integer but the question seems to be framed slightly differently, even though the answers are the same.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are right, I have edited my post with that.