# Program loops infinitely if a non-integer is entered, and does not accept plural digit inputs

Tags: c

Assigned task is to ask for # of values, and then at the end output the minimum, maximum, and average values and at this point I've run out of bug fixes

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int ErrorDetection = 1;
    char valCounter;
    int valnumber;
    int Incrementer;
    int StoredValue;
    int MinimumValue = 100;
    int MaximumValue = 0;
    float Average;
    int AddToStored;
    int Sum = 0;

    printf("MIN, MAX, and MEAN CALCULATOR\n\n");

    while (ErrorDetection != 0)
    {
        printf("How many values are to be entered?\n");
        scanf("%s", &valCounter);

        if (valCounter > '0' && valCounter < '9') {
            ErrorDetection = 0;
        }
        else {
            ErrorDetection = 1;
            printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
        }
        valCounter = valCounter - 47;
    }

    for (Incrementer = 1; Incrementer < valCounter; Incrementer++)
    {
        ErrorDetection = 1;

        while (ErrorDetection != 0) {
            printf("Value %d: ", Incrementer);
            scanf(" %d", &StoredValue);

            if (StoredValue > 0 && StoredValue < 9) {
                ErrorDetection = 0;
            }
            else {
                ErrorDetection = 1;
                printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (StoredValue > MaximumValue) {
            MaximumValue = StoredValue;
        }
        if (StoredValue <= MinimumValue) {
            MinimumValue = StoredValue;
        }
        Sum = Sum + StoredValue;
    }

    valCounter = valCounter - 1;
    Average = (float)Sum / (float)valCounter;

    printf(
        "Minimum value is %d, maximum value is %d, and average value is %g.\n",
        MinimumValue, MaximumValue, Average
    );
}
```

If you input a 2 digit number things begin to breakdown, but at the same time I don't know how to go through with errorchecking if I allow multiple digit answers, as I make use of ASCII conversions to check if an input is a number or not.

Comment: Note that you only allow a count between 1 and 8 inclusive.  I can see eliminating 0; why not allow 9 too?  Using `valCounter = valCounter - 47;` would be better written using `'0'` (48) — `valCounter -= '0' - 1;` to subtract 47.  I'm not sure why you have the 47; it means that `'1'` maps to `2`, and so on.  Be cautious with magic numbers!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is why OP is starting loop from `1` instead of `0`. A work around to solve bug you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behavior here.

```
     char valCounter;

    scanf("%s", &valCounter);
```

You have declared `valCounter` as `char` type but trying to read `string` type.

Hence change the `scanf` to.

```
scanf("%c", &valCounter);
```

---

**I would suggest you declare `valCounter` as `int`**

```
int valCounter;
scanf("%d", &valCounter);
```

in that case your `if` will become.

```
if ((valCounter > 0) && (valCounter < 9))
```

and you don't need

```
valCounter = valCounter - 47; //remove
```

Also your `for` loop should start from 0 instead of 1

```
for(Incrementer = 1 ; Incrementer < valCounter; Incrementer++)
```

should be

```
for(Incrementer = 0 ; Incrementer < valCounter; Incrementer++)
```

Comment: If I change incrementer to 0 then asking for 1 value gives me 
"Value 1:
Value 2:"

Comment: @DylanWolfer You should subtract `valCounter = valCounter - '0';` instead of `valCounter = valCounter - 47;`. Did you see jonathan lefler comment regarding the same?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here.

```
char valCounter;
scanf("%s", &valCounter);
```

You're telling `scanf` to read a string, but you're passing it the address of a character. You should be asking for an integer, and giving it the address of an integer.

```
int valCounter;
scanf("%d", &valCounter)
```

There's more information here, including reasons why `scanf` might not be the best idea:
[How to scanf only integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583717/how-to-scanf-only-integer)

Comment: Done the above and changed the error detection from character values to integer values, but now if there is a 2 digit input for the number of values, say for example 14, the 1 is used as number of values and the 4 is used for value 1, rather than 14 being used for the initial value

Comment: And the program also loops if a non integer number is entered still

Comment: If you read the link, I think you'll find a lot of relevant information. I think some of it was definitely relevant to how to avoid reading too much or too little data from the input stream.

Comment: So how would I use fgetc to store a variable in the same way scanf does?