# Scanf returns 1 instead of 0 when an error occurres

Tags: c, input, return, scanf, c99

I have read that the returned value of `scanf` indicates if it successfully was able to read and convert values.
I have using the returned value to detect if the input is an integer or not but if the input was `4.5` `scanf` returns 1 while if the input was `g` `scanf` returns 0.
Her's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    int ReturnedValue=scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Scanf Returned:%d",ReturnedValue);
    return 0;
}
```

in Multiple different articles you suggested to use the returned value of `scanf` to detect for integers but why this didn't work now?

Comment: because scanf could parse 4 out of your string. It's enough for scanf to be happy.

Comment: but how could I detect if it's integer or not in simple fast way without destroying my whole code in c?

Comment: Quote from the man page: *On  success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.*. The input `4.5` would match the 4 and assign it to `&x` and leave `.5` behind in the buffer. Hence it returns 1.

Comment: "but how could I detect if it's integer or not in simple fast way without destroying my whole code in c?" `scanf` is the wrong function for that. Better read the whole line with `fgets` and parse it using better functions like `strtol`, `stroul`, etc. See 
Jean-François Fabre's answer.

Comment: *but how could I detect if it's integer or not in simple fast way?* By **not using `scanf`**.  There are a few (a very few) things `scanf` is good for, but reading integers *and* accurately complaining if non-integer input is received is simply not one of them.  Be nice to yourself: don't waste any more time on `scanf`; [learn about some better alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-to-parse-input-instead-of-scanf).

Answer (score 5):

The return value is not signaling success or failure. It is the number of successfully converted values.

That's why you got "1" on "4.5" with `"%d"` as format, the "4" was converted.

You would have found this by reading the documentation of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that `scanf` (or `atoi`) aren't really reliable to parse integers.

In your case, `scanf` finds `4` and is happy with that, which explains the 1 return code.

A safest way is to use the `strtol`, `strtoul` .. primitives that make sure that the *word* is valid as an integer (for more details check [How to scanf only integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583717/how-to-scanf-only-integer) where the answer is "don't use `scanf`" BTW :))

In your particular case (stuck with `scanf`), you *could* make input more robust by scanning as *float* first (using `%f` on a float variable). And checking if the floating point value is an *integer*.

```
float xf;
if (scanf("%f",&xf) == 1)
{
     // one integer or float was scanned
     x = (int)xf;
     if (x==xf)
     {
        // scanned value is an integer: valid
     }
}
```

But inputs like `4XXXX` would still be wrongly accepted. If you *have* to use `scanf`, then you have to accept a degree of risk.

Comment: How to check that input is an integer?

Comment: I am forced to use scanf in collage

Comment: maybe by first scanning with %f format to detect extra dot… edited. But still not the best solution.

Comment: @John sadly a lot of people use the `scanf` family of function incorrectly and teachers (and books and tutorial) make the mistake of teaching `scanf` as the way to read from the user. But `scanf` is not there to read random user data but they "scan[s] input according to [a] format". User input is random, can have errors, be incomplete and sometimes is very hard to find a good pattern to catch it all. Because these functions scan the input, when they fail, they leave stuff in the buffer behind which can be a big gotcha, when you don't know what your are doing...

Comment: ok but how to detect if the number has dot? to me 2.0 is not an integer

Comment: My advice would be not to use `scanf` to read from the user but use `fgets` to get the whole line and the user better functions to parse the input. Bending `scanf` to accept/deny all kind of inputs will only end in frustration.

Comment: @John use `strtol`. The second parameter of `strtol` is a pointer to a `char*` that is set to the first non-integer character in the stream. If the whole c-string is an integer, then deference to `'\0'`, something else otherwise. That's how you do it.

Comment: If you simply *have* to use `scanf`, if some ninny has forbidden the use of superior alternatives like `fgets`, I suppose you could read lines using `scanf("%99[^\n]\n", linebuf);`, and then operate on `linebuf` as you would have done after calling `fgets`, if you were allowed to.

Comment: *I am forced to use scanf in college.* If it were me, I would just ignore that requirement.  `scanf` is square training wheels.  No real C programmers use it for anything; its sole purpose is to frustrate beginners as they desperately try to use it to get numbers into their beginning programs to work on.  The sooner you can abandon it and [move on to better alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-to-parse-input-instead-of-scanf), the better.

Answer (score 0):

> I have using the returned value to detect if the input is an integer or not but if the input was 4.5 scanf returns 1 while if the input was g scanf returns 0.

That actually makes sense in this case.

int ReturnedValue=scanf("%d",&x);

Remember `scanf` return value is the number of items parsed correctly.

- If you enter 4.5, it only reads the first digit 4 and interprets the `int` value correctly. It discards all the remaining invalid characters from the input.
- If you enter `d`, then scanf fails completely (it cannot parse any int) and so it returns 0.

Refer to the scanf manual - to see why 4.5 is parsed as integer 4:

> Reading of characters stops either when this maximum
>                 is reached or when a nonmatching character is found, whichever
>                 happens first.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: How to check that input is an integer?

Comment: Generally you can't prevent user from entering a double and scanf interpret it as an int.

Answer (score 0):

I initially didn't want to write an answer and left comments behind. I'd like
to expand on [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59078835/1480131)'s answer.

The problem with the `scanf` family is that they don't do what most people
believe they do and then they are left confused as to why it does something "strange". In reality they scan input based on an format and assign values to
variables (passed via pointers). When they encounter an error, i.a. something
doesn't match to the format, then they stop.

With the format `"%d"` you are just saying read an integer. The format doesn't
say "read an integer and only an integer". To do that you would need to also
exclude everything else and if I'm not mistaken it would be something like
this `"%d[^0-9]*"` (I haven't tested it to see if I'm right).
That's why the user input `4.5` is accepted by
`scanf`. Note that `scanf` is not doing it incorrectly, you are specifying it
incorrectly, because you assume, that `"%d"` means "and integer and integer
only".

As you can see, it is pretty hard to come up with a format that catches
everything and also tells you when the user made an error. User input aka what
the user enters is random and can contain (unintentionally) errors, miss the
format, etc. So you end up with very complex formats to just determine if the
user added a dot at the end and fail if the user does that.

That's why my advice is to read the while input via `fgets` and then use something better
to parse the input like `strtol` or even `sscanf` if you have a good format.

Here an example for the usage of `strtol`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *entries[] = { "4.5", "4", "some random text" };
    char *ptr;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof entries / sizeof *entries; ++i)
    {
        long int res = strtol(entries[i], &ptr, 0);

        if(*ptr != '\0') {
            printf("The input '%s' is not an integer. The non-integer is '%s'\n", entries[i], ptr);
        } else {
            printf("The input '%s' is an integer: %ld\n", entries[i], res);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which returns

```
The input '4.5' is not an integer. The non-integer is '.5'
The input '4' is an integer: 4
The input 'some random text' is not an integer. The non-integer is 'some random text'
```

This is a more precise way to check if the whole input is an integer or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Scanf returns 1 instead of 0 when an error occurs

An error did not occur in input.  The first character `"4"` converts nicely to a `4`.  Code needs to examine the rest of the line.

> I am forced to use scanf in collage

Such coding constraints are unfortunate.  `fgets()/strtol()` would be better.

> how could I detect if it's integer or not in simple fast way without destroying my whole code in c?

Scan for the integer and look for trailing junk.

```
char endchar;  
int cnt = scanf("%d%c",&x, &endchar);
if (cnt == EOF) puts("End-of-file occurred");
else if (cnt == 1 || (cnt == 2 && endchar == '\n')) printf("Success %d\n", x);
else puts("Non-integer input");
```

When data is *non-integer input*, some offending characters may remain in `stdin`.  As this task is only to read one `int`, that is OK.

Production code would more likely read a *line* and then parse it.