# How to prevent non-integer input in c?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am trying to run a program whereby user can only enter 1 or 2. If the user enters any other numbers or alphabets, it should prompt the user back to entering input again. I have tried the following code and it works if user enter an integer which is not 1 or 2, but the whole program will go haywire if entered any alphabets. I tried to validate with

if == 0 but doesnt work as well. Does anyone have any idea?

> ```
> int getUserInput(){
>
> printf("1: You have chosen 1.\n");
> printf("2: You have chosen 2.\n\n");
>
> printf("Enter an option: ");
> scanf("%d", &userSel);
>
> if(userSel!= 1 && userSel!= 2){
>     
>     printf("You have entered an invalid input. Please try again.\n");
>     getUserInput();
> }
> else{
>     printf("Enter a number: ");
>     scanf("%d", &userNo);
> }
>
> printf("userSelection: %d\n", userSel);
> printf("1userNumber: %d\n", userNo);
>
> return 0; 
> }
> ```

Comment: Rather than `scanf(any_format, ...)`, use `fgets()` to read a _line_ of user input into a _string_.  Then process that _string_.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make it so scanf sets the variable that will hold the user input only when the input is a integer. You can use this stack overflow link here that has a similar question to yours!

[How to scanf only integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583717/how-to-scanf-only-integer)