# How do I reprompt a user to input a numerical value only?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float change;
    do 
    {
        printf("Change: ");
    }while(scanf("%f", &change) == 0);
    printf("Good");
}
```

Comment: You can be stuck in an infinite loop if the user types, for example, "forty two<ENTER>". Better use `fgets()` for user input. You can follow `fgets()` with `strtod()`...

Comment: Begin by reading *strings* (actually full lines) and then attempt to parse it as a number (using e.g. `strtod`).

Comment: Follow the approach of using `fgets`, https://stackoverflow.com/q/26583717/14973743

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scanf only integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583717/how-to-scanf-only-integer)